# Unable to parse Array Type Query string to List of Object

Tags: arrays, asp.net-core-mvc, custom-model-binder

I am trying some paging and sorting stuffs in ASP.net core MVC 6 application. But when I pass array like query string MVC action unable to parse it to list.

Query String looks like :

> take=10&skip=0&page=1&pageSize=10&sort%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=price&sort%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc

Model for it looks like:

[image]

This is the query string which i am getting at server: 
[image]

Count for Sort Array or List is always 0.
[image]

Can you please suggest a work around. It should parse it correctly but not getting where things are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your current decoded query string looks like

```
take=10&skip=0&page=1&pageSize=10&sort[0][field]=price&sort[0][dir]=asc
```

So use following format to pass query string parameters from your client application

```
sort[0].field=price&sort[0].dir=asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone may have a better answer, but if it were me I'd simplify my query string a bit and flatten the model. So the query string might be:

`take=10&skip=0&page=1&pageSize=10&sortfield1=price&sortdir1=asc&sortfield2=otherfield&sortdir2=desc`

Then in the model replace `public List<Sort> Sort` with the flattened properties:

```
 public string SortField1 {get; set;}
 public string SortDir1   {get; set;}
 public string SortField2 {get; set;}
 public string SortDir2   {get; set;}
```

You can add as many of these flattened properties as needed.  It's not elegant, but it gets the job done.  Then if you need your Sort list built you can build it from these properties easily.

Comment: That's fine, there are various work around of this but I'm looking for the reason why this problem occurring at my code. I might be missing something.

Comment: @SundarSingh  How about and upvote?.  I did answer your question "Can you please suggest a work around."